# How to combine a mapping with aggregates with (and without) animation by years and still colorize land with missing values?

Tags: python, aggregate, plotly-python, choropleth

1. I'm trying to add an aggregate function to my choropleth.
   On the latter I had managed, thanks to @RobRaymond, to obtain an animation by year while displaying the countries with a missing value with their names.

On the Plotly site [https://plotly.com/python/aggregations/] I saw that we could obtain a mapping with aggregates.

I tried to add it to my code but I can't get my expected result.
What did I miss?

My code:

```py
import plotly.io as pio
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# need to know countries that make up natural earth...
world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_lowres"))

data = {"Country helped": 
        ['Afghanistan', 'Algérie', 'Angola', 'Bangladesh', 'Bénin',
       'Bhoutan', 'Bolivie (État plurinational de)', 'Burkina Faso',
       'Burundi', 'Cambodge', 'Cameroun', 'Colombie', 'Comores', 'Congo',
       "Côte d'Ivoire", 'Cuba', 'Djibouti', 'Égypte', 'El Salvador',
       'Équateur', 'Éthiopie', 'Gambie', 'Géorgie', 'Ghana', 'Guatemala',
       'Guinée', 'Guinée-Bissau', 'Haïti', 'Honduras',
       "Iran (République islamique d')", 'Iraq', 'Jordanie', 'Kenya',
       'Kirghizistan', 'Lesotho', 'Liban', 'Libéria', 'Libye',
       'Madagascar', 'Malawi', 'Mali', 'Mauritanie', 'Mozambique',
       'Myanmar', 'Népal', 'Nicaragua', 'Niger', 'Ouganda', 'Pakistan',
       'Palestine', 'Philippines', 'République arabe syrienne',
       'République centrafricaine', 'République démocratique du Congo',
       'République démocratique populaire lao', 'République dominicaine',
       'République populaire démocratique de Corée',
       'République-Unie de Tanzanie', 'Rwanda', 'Sao Tomé-et-Principe',
       'Sénégal', 'Sierra Leone', 'Somalie', 'Soudan', 'Soudan du Sud',
       'Sri Lanka', 'Tadjikistan', 'Tchad', 'Timor-Leste', 'Togo',
       'Vanuatu', 'Yémen', 'Zambie', 'Zimbabwe'],
        "Code zone (ISO3)": 
        ['AFG', 'DZA', 'AGO', 'BGD', 'BEN', 'BTN', 'BOL', 'BFA', 'BDI',
       'KHM', 'CMR', 'COL', 'COM', 'COG', 'CIV', 'CUB', 'DJI', 'EGY',
       'SLV', 'ECU', 'ETH', 'GMB', 'GEO', 'GHA', 'GTM', 'GIN', 'GNB',
       'HTI', 'HND', 'IRN', 'IRQ', 'JOR', 'KEN', 'KGZ', 'LSO', 'LBN',
       'LBR', 'LBY', 'MDG', 'MWI', 'MLI', 'MRT', 'MOZ', 'MMR', 'NPL',
       'NIC', 'NER', 'UGA', 'PAK', 'PSE', 'PHL', 'SYR', 'CAF', 'COD',
       'LAO', 'DOM', 'PRK', 'TZA', 'RWA', 'STP', 'SEN', 'SLE', 'SOM',
       'SDN', 'SSD', 'LKA', 'TJK', 'TCD', 'TLS', 'TGO', 'VUT', 'YEM',
       'ZMB', 'ZWE'],
       "Product":
        ['Autres non-céréales', 'Blé et Farin', 'Céréales',
       'Fruits secs, total', 'Huiles végétales',
       'Légumineuses Sèches,Tot.', 'Non-céréales', 'Riz, total',
       'Sucre, total', 'Céréales Secondaires', 'Lait, total',
       'Mélanges et préparations', 'Poiss&produi', 'BulgurFarEnt',
       'Viande Total', 'Graisses Com'],
        "Year": 
        ['2013', '2014', '2015', '2016'],
        "Quantity of donated products": np.random.random_integers(90, 40000, 65)
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ["Country helped", "Code zone (ISO3)",
                                   "Product", "Année", "Quantity of donated products"])



aggs = ["count","sum","avg","median","mode","rms","stddev","min","max","first","last"]

agg = []
agg_func = []
for i in range(0, len(aggs)):
    agg = dict(
        args=['transforms[0].aggregations[0].func', aggs[i]],
        label=aggs[i],
        method='restyle'
    )
    agg_func.append(agg)



# Utilisation de plotly.express pour l'animation
data = [dict(df,
             type = 'choropleth',
             locations = df["Code zone (ISO3)"],
             z = df["Quantity of donated products"],
             color="z",
             color_continuous_scale="earth_r",
             animation_frame=df["Year"],
             hover_name="Country helped",
             hover_data=["Product"],
             transforms = [dict(
                 type = 'aggregate',
                 groups = df["Code zone (ISO3)"],
                 aggregations = [dict(
                     target = 'z', func = 'sum', enabled = True)
                                ]
             )]
            )
       ]

layout = dict(
    autosize=True,
    title = "<b>Evolution of food aid in the world from 2013 to 2016</b><br>use dropdown to change aggregation",
    yaxis = dict(title = 'Score', range = [0,22]),
    geo=dict(
        landcolor="lightgray",
        showland=True,
        showcountries=True,
        countrycolor="gray",
        countrywidth=0.5,
        showframe=False,
        showcoastlines=False,
        projection_type="natural earth",
        showocean=True, oceancolor="lightBlue",
        showlakes=True, lakecolor="lightblue",
        showrivers=True, rivercolor="lightblue"
    ),
    annotations=[
        dict(
            x=0.55,
            y=0.15,
            xref="paper",
            yref="paper",
            text='Source: <a href="https://www.fao.org/faostat/fr/#data">\
            FAO</a>',
            showarrow=False
        )
    ],
    updatemenus = [dict(
        x = 0.95,
        y = 1.10,
        xref = 'paper',
        yref = 'paper',
        yanchor = 'top',
        active = 1,
        showactive = False,
        buttons = agg_func
    )],
    coloraxis2={"colorscale": [[0, "lightgray"], [1, "lightgray"]], "showscale": False}
)


fig.layout.updatemenus[0].buttons[0].args[1]['frame']['duration'] = 2000
fig.layout.updatemenus[0].buttons[0].args[1]['transition']['duration'] = 1000

# update each of the animation frames with missing countries
for fr in fig.frames:
    tr_missing = (
        px.choropleth(
            world.loc[~world["iso_a3"].isin(fr.data[0]["locations"]), "iso_a3"]
            .to_frame()
            .assign(color=1),
            color="color",
            locations="iso_a3"            
        )
        .update_traces(hovertemplate="%{location} : Datas manquantes",
                       coloraxis="coloraxis2"
                      )
        .data[0]
    )
    fr.update(data=[fr.data[0], tr_missing])

# re-construct the figure...
fig_dict = go.Figure(data=fig.frames[0].data, layout=fig.layout, frames=fig.frames)

pio.show(fig_dict, validate=True)
```

2. I didn't find how to just additional missing trace gets appended to trace in data if i want to take off the `animation_frame=df["Year"]`

**Edit 2:**

- provide data sample as text
- translate columns in english
- trying to make my code easier to test
- add a question

**Edit 1:**

[The plot i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usV13.jpg)

[Here is a sample of df_world_aide_alim](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GK84.jpg)

[A second sample: df_world_aide_alim.head(25)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bUjq.jpg)

[The dropdown to change aggregation i tried to combine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SAlW.jpg)

Comment: can you update question to provide sample data in `df_world_aide_alim` I would not go with plotly aggregations as they are clearly deprecated.  I would use pandas

Comment: Of course, I apologize for not putting these samples before, I hope this is what you expected.

Comment: can you provide either of the data samples as text rather than an image so that I can use as data.

Comment: It's done. I updated my code to make it easier to test and understand.

Comment: updated answer - it's all the combinations of capabilities you noted.  With all coding it's being structured and clear.  animation and drop down selections make no sense...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- the code supplied to create a dataframe fails.  Providing a **dict** to `pd.DataFrame()` all the lists need to be same length.  Have synthesized a dataframe from this **dict** creating all lists of same length (plus as a side effect of this, make sure country name and code are consistent)
- have used **pandas** [named aggregations](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/user_guide/groupby.html#groupby-aggregate-named) to create all of the analytics you want.  Note there are a few that don't map 1:1 between deprecated **plotly** names and approach needed in **pandas**
- within `build_fig()` now have data frame *dfa* (with list of aggregations and no animation)

| Code zone (ISO3) | count | sum | avg | median | mode | rms | stddev | min | max | first | last | Country helped | Product |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AFG | 3 | 46647 | 15549 | 12358 | 5086 | 32115.5 | 12371.1 | 5086 | 29203 | 12358 | 29203 | Afghanistan | ['Huiles végétales', 'Céréales', 'Sucre, total'] |
| AGO | 5 | 75067 | 15013.4 | 14357 | 2187 | 38317.9 | 9236.46 | 2187 | 26697 | 14357 | 26697 | Angola | ['Riz, total', 'Fruits secs, total', 'Céréales Secondaires', 'Poiss&produi'] |

- clearly from this structure a *trace* can be created from each of the columns.  By default make first one visible (*count*)
- add missing countries *trace*
- create **updatemenus** to control *trace* visibility based on selection which *missing* always being visible

```
build_fig(df)
```

[image]

- animation is similar.  Without using **dash** as well I don't see an option of having multiple analytics per frame selected from drop down.  Hence example of animation and one analytic. Clearly for animation you need another dimension in data, year has been used for this.

```
build_fig(df, aggs="rms", group=["Code zone (ISO3)", "Year"])
```

[image]

#### embedded list more sophisticated aggregate function

```
build_fig(
    df,
    agg_cols={
        "Country helped": ("Country helped", "first"),
        "Product": (
            "Product",
            lambda s: df.loc[s.index]
            .sort_values("Quantity of donated products", ascending=False)
            .loc[:, "Product"]
            .head(3),
        ),
    },
)
```

#### full code

```
import plotly.io as pio
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math


# fmt: off
data = {"Country helped": 
        ['Afghanistan', 'Algérie', 'Angola', 'Bangladesh', 'Bénin',
       'Bhoutan', 'Bolivie (État plurinational de)', 'Burkina Faso',
       'Burundi', 'Cambodge', 'Cameroun', 'Colombie', 'Comores', 'Congo',
       "Côte d'Ivoire", 'Cuba', 'Djibouti', 'Égypte', 'El Salvador',
       'Équateur', 'Éthiopie', 'Gambie', 'Géorgie', 'Ghana', 'Guatemala',
       'Guinée', 'Guinée-Bissau', 'Haïti', 'Honduras',
       "Iran (République islamique d')", 'Iraq', 'Jordanie', 'Kenya',
       'Kirghizistan', 'Lesotho', 'Liban', 'Libéria', 'Libye',
       'Madagascar', 'Malawi', 'Mali', 'Mauritanie', 'Mozambique',
       'Myanmar', 'Népal', 'Nicaragua', 'Niger', 'Ouganda', 'Pakistan',
       'Palestine', 'Philippines', 'République arabe syrienne',
       'République centrafricaine', 'République démocratique du Congo',
       'République démocratique populaire lao', 'République dominicaine',
       'République populaire démocratique de Corée',
       'République-Unie de Tanzanie', 'Rwanda', 'Sao Tomé-et-Principe',
       'Sénégal', 'Sierra Leone', 'Somalie', 'Soudan', 'Soudan du Sud',
       'Sri Lanka', 'Tadjikistan', 'Tchad', 'Timor-Leste', 'Togo',
       'Vanuatu', 'Yémen', 'Zambie', 'Zimbabwe'],
        "Code zone (ISO3)": 
        ['AFG', 'DZA', 'AGO', 'BGD', 'BEN', 'BTN', 'BOL', 'BFA', 'BDI',
       'KHM', 'CMR', 'COL', 'COM', 'COG', 'CIV', 'CUB', 'DJI', 'EGY',
       'SLV', 'ECU', 'ETH', 'GMB', 'GEO', 'GHA', 'GTM', 'GIN', 'GNB',
       'HTI', 'HND', 'IRN', 'IRQ', 'JOR', 'KEN', 'KGZ', 'LSO', 'LBN',
       'LBR', 'LBY', 'MDG', 'MWI', 'MLI', 'MRT', 'MOZ', 'MMR', 'NPL',
       'NIC', 'NER', 'UGA', 'PAK', 'PSE', 'PHL', 'SYR', 'CAF', 'COD',
       'LAO', 'DOM', 'PRK', 'TZA', 'RWA', 'STP', 'SEN', 'SLE', 'SOM',
       'SDN', 'SSD', 'LKA', 'TJK', 'TCD', 'TLS', 'TGO', 'VUT', 'YEM',
       'ZMB', 'ZWE'],
       "Product":
        ['Autres non-céréales', 'Blé et Farin', 'Céréales',
       'Fruits secs, total', 'Huiles végétales',
       'Légumineuses Sèches,Tot.', 'Non-céréales', 'Riz, total',
       'Sucre, total', 'Céréales Secondaires', 'Lait, total',
       'Mélanges et préparations', 'Poiss&produi', 'BulgurFarEnt',
       'Viande Total', 'Graisses Com'],
        "Year": 
        ['2013', '2014', '2015', '2016'],
        "Quantity of donated products": np.random.randint(90, 40000, 500)
        }
# fmt: on

# this fails !!!
# df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ["Country helped", "Code zone (ISO3)",
#                                    "Product", "Année", "Quantity of donated products"])

# provided data is ragged, different lengths for each column, make all arrays same length for data frame
df = (
    pd.DataFrame(
        {
            k: data[k] if len(data[k]) == c else np.random.choice(data[k], c)
            for k in data.keys()
            if (c := max({k: len(data[k]) for k in data.keys()}.values()))
        }
    )
    .drop(columns=["Country helped"])
    .merge(
        pd.DataFrame(
            {
                k: v
                for k, v in data.items()
                if k in ["Country helped", "Code zone (ISO3)"]
            }
        ),
        on="Code zone (ISO3)",
        how="inner",
    )
)

aggs = [
    "count",
    "sum",
    "avg",
    "median",
    "mode",
    "rms",
    "stddev",
    "min",
    "max",
    "first",
    "last",
]


def build_fig(df,
    aggs=aggs,
    analytical_col="Quantity of donated products",
    group=["Code zone (ISO3)"],
    agg_cols={
        "Country helped": ("Country helped", "first"),
        "Product": ("Product", lambda s: s.unique().tolist()),
    },
):
    # make sure argument permutations make sense
    assert (len(group) == 1 and isinstance(aggs, list)) or (
        len(group) == 2 and isinstance(aggs, str)
    )
    
    # need to know countries that make up natural earth...
    world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_lowres"))

    # pandas aggregate functions don't map 1:1 to deprecated plotly functions
    override = {
        "avg": "mean",
        "mode": lambda s: s.mode().iloc[0],
        "rms": lambda s: math.sqrt((s ** 2).sum()),
        "stddev": "std",
    }

    # create dataframe with all wanted aggregates as columns, plus keep country name and list of products
    dfa = df.groupby(group, as_index=False).agg(
        **{
            **{
                agg: (
                    analytical_col,
                    agg if agg not in override.keys() else override[agg],
                )
                for agg in (aggs if isinstance(aggs, list) else [aggs])
            },
            **agg_cols,
        }
    )

    # generate trace of missing countries to be included where necessary
    def missing(values):
        return (
            px.choropleth(
                world.loc[~world["iso_a3"].isin(values), "iso_a3"],
                locations="iso_a3",
            )
            .update_traces(
                name="missing",
                colorscale=[[0, "red"], [1, "red"]],
                showlegend=False,
                hovertemplate="missing: %{location}",
            )
            .data
        )

    # create a trace for each required aggregate
    if len(group) == 1:
        fig = go.Figure(
            [
                t.update(name=agg, visible=(isinstance(aggs, str) or aggs[0] == agg))
                for agg in (aggs if isinstance(aggs, list) else [aggs])
                for t in px.choropleth(
                    dfa, locations=group[0], color=agg, hover_data=list(agg_cols.keys())
                ).data
            ]
        )

        # add the missing layer
        fig.add_traces(missing(fig.data[0]["locations"]))

        # add the drop down menu...
        fig.update_layout(
            updatemenus=[
                {
                    "buttons": [
                        {
                            "label": agg,
                            "method": "restyle",
                            "args": [
                                {
                                    "visible": [
                                        t.name == agg or t.name == "missing"
                                        for t in fig.data
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                        }
                        for agg in aggs
                    ]
                }
            ]
        )

    # generate an animation, with only one aggregation
    else:
        fig = px.choropleth(
            dfa,
            locations=group[0],
            color=aggs,
            animation_frame=group[1],
            hover_data=list(agg_cols.keys()),
        )

        # update each of the animation frames with missing countries
        for fr in fig.frames:
            fr.update(data=[fr.data[0], missing(fr.data[0]["locations"])[0]])

        # re-construct the figure...
        fig = go.Figure(data=fig.frames[0].data, layout=fig.layout, frames=fig.frames)

    return fig
```

Comment: Thank you so much Rob! I begin to understand the meaning of each line, even if some areas are still dark. Thank you for detailing your code, it really helps to progress.

Comment: Just one more question: in `agg_cols`, i tried to order the list of the Product by a list of the 3 most products gifted by countries but in vain.
I tried with :  
`agg_cols={"Country helped": ("Country helped", "first"), "Product": sorted("Product", key=lambda s: s(df.groupby("Country helped")["Quantity of donated products"].sort(by="Quantity of donated products", ascending=False))).head(3).tolist()}`

I get this typeError: "'bool' object is not callable"

Is it possible to do it?

Comment: `build_fig(
    df,
    agg_cols={
        "Country helped": ("Country helped", "first"),
        "Product": ("Product", lambda s: s.value_counts().index[0:2]),
    },
)` will do what you want.  really comes down to how familiar you are with **pandas**

Comment: Thanks, but this returns a list of 2 products like a `"Product": ("Product", lambda s: s.head(2))` but without taking into account the value associated with the "Quantity of donated products" column.

I would like that in the "Product" column the object (for example "Rice") which is associated with the highest value of the "Quantity of donated products" column is the one that is returned.

Comment: it's all in definition, *3 most products gifted by countries* most commonly appearing product is what I gave you.   If definition is not this then use a different aggregate function

Comment: have added to answer - get familiar with **pandas** and **lambda** functions and any custom definition u wanna come up with can be done

Comment: I still have a lot to learn, thank you for taking the time. Everything works as I wanted, thank you very much!